# TYPO3 click on menu item should only update part of page

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a page build with TyYPO3 V9. I have to split the page somewhere in 2 parts.
In the first part, I call it the header section. In the header section there is are an image, buttons and a player.
After the header section is the menu followed by part of the page which changed depending on the menu item.

I have the problem, that if a menu item is clicked the whole page will updated, even the player. The result is, that the player stops and has always started again.

Is there any possibility that TYPO3 only refreshes the menu and the part below the menu?

Comment: It is common to add All the detail you can when writing questions. Without knowing the code how can Anyone be asked to solve a situation like yours? Is the code yours? Does it contain Javascript? Without more information, it does not warrant keeping your question active.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is AJAX.
There is no build in mechanism in TYPO3 for this. Especially as you want to change the menu and some content.

But you can build it by yourself:
add some javascript to modify the menu entries and trigger a javascript routine which calls the whole page and extract relevant parts to replace in current page.
Or provide an additional page type which provides only your needed data (menu and main content) e.g. as a JSON.

---

Edit:

As I have no example ready to use I can't copy it here.
Regarding AJAX you should find a lot of examples and libraries. Depending on your preferred javascript framework (I will use jquery) there should be some nice routines.

first you need a javascript function which replaces the main content by another piece of html.

```js
function replaceContent(replpaceHTML) {
$('#content').html(replaceHTML);
}
```

Then you need a provider for this HTML.
as you use TYPO3 you can define another page-type with a special rendering, so there is returned only the main content without HTML-header and without the header and footer of the page.

```
AJAX = page
AJAX {
   typeNum = 12345
   config {
      disableAllHeaderCode = 1
      disablePrefixComment = true
      metaCharset = UTF-8
   }

   10 < styles.content.get
}
```

now you could get the main content of each page with `https://domain.tld/index.php?id=123&type=12345`.

As your menu contains regular links you need to change the behavior of your menu: add an eventhandler to each link which calls a javascript routine instead of following the link.

```js
$('.menuitem').onClick(function (event) {
   var url = $this.attr('href');
   $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url + '?type=12345', // assuming complete URLs without parameters
    complete: function(data){
      var newContent = $(data.responseText);
      replaceContent(newContent);
    }
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

that would contain the usual drawbacks of AJAX: content and URL does not match any more so bookmarking the current content (/page) is not possible. also there is no history.
But there are solutions with further javascript.

Comment: Bernd, maybe I have not pointed out it clear enough. I don't want change the menu, but the menu is changed when I press an item. If I use JSON for what I use Typo3?
The only changes I need is to take care, that the part I called header is not changed or protected for Typo3 updates.

Comment: depending on the kind and styling of the menu you may need to change the menu (ACT and CUR may change). anyway: you need an AJAX routine in your page which calls the (main) content from TYPO3 for a page selected in the menu. this could be done with an additional *pagetype*. whether you provide JSON or HTML stubs depend on you. AJAX is flexible and so is rendering in TYPO3.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what I should do? I put the header part into a iframe, but also this iframe is updated by Typo3. What I really need is some mechanismn, which avoid to update the header part or that Typo3 is only part where the content should chaged and not the whole page. I already use jquery load to refresh automatically a part of the screen. But I still want use typo3 when somebody ist clicking a menu item. So please explain, how I can use a AJAX call to avoid it.

Comment: I sketched the use of ajax in my answer.